# EF TPT inheritance and self references

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have the following structure of EF entities classes:

```
    public abstract class CalendarItem
    {
        public Guid CalendarItemId { get; set; }
        public Guid? ParentCalendarItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual CalendarItem ParentCalendarItem { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CalendarItem> ChildCalendarItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class CalendarSlot : CalendarItem
    {
        public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }
    }

    public class CalendarSession : CalendarEvent
    {
        public DateTimeOffset StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset EndDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping is configured as follows:

```
    public class CalendarItemMap
    {
        public static void Map(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CalendarItem>().ToTable("CalendarItem");
            modelBuilder.Entity<CalendarItem>().HasKey(t => t.CalendarItemId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CalendarItem>().HasOne(ci => ci.ParentCalendarItem)
                .WithMany(cs => cs.ChildCalendarItems).HasForeignKey(cs => cs.ParentCalendarItemId);
        }
    }
```

With DbSets as:

```
        public DbSet<CalendarItem> CalendarItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CalendarSession> CalendarSessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CalendarSlot> CalendarSlots { get; set; }
```

My question is how to properly organize self-reference (tree) structure of the base class with inheritance provided. All types of entities, namely CalendarSlot and CalendarSession should have references to themselves, CalendarItem cannot be created as an instance.
In the database the tree structure is implemented in the CalendarItem table. CalendarSlot/CalendarSession tables have 1-1 relationship with CalendarItem.

The problem is that in my code I have a place with generic method which converts models to contracts for the API:

```
        internal static TContract ToCalendarItem<TContract, TModel>(TModel calendarItemModel)
            where TContract : Contract.CalendarItem, new()
            where TModel : Model.CalendarItem
        {
            return new()
            {
                CalendarItemId = calendarItemModel.CalendarItemId,
                Name = calendarItemModel.Name,
                Description = calendarItemModel.Description,
                ParentCalendarItem = calendarItemModel.ParentCalendarItem != null ? ToCalendarItem<TContract, TModel>(calendarItemModel.ParentCalendarItem) : null
            };
        }
```

and in the line

```
ParentCalendarItem = calendarItemModel.ParentCalendarItem != null ? ToCalendarItem<TContract, TModel>(calendarItemModel.ParentCalendarItem) : null
```

I have an error **"Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'Model.CalendarItem' to TModel"**.
How can I tell the system that `calendarItemModel.ParentCalendarItem` should always be TModel (a class derived from `Model.CalendarItem`)?

What I am doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are different ways to implement hierarchical data in the database. What you have chosen is called the **adjacency list**. Google for this term. Check out this [article](https://habr.com/en/post/516596/).

Comment: Some DBMSs have built-in tools for representing hierarchies. For example, the ltree module in Postgresql or the HierarchyId type in Sql Server. Both are a **materialized path**. Check out this [article](https://www.meziantou.net/using-hierarchyid-with-entity-framework-core.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the references @AlexanderPetrov, it was very interesting to know some more details in this field. 
However my question was mainly what should I do to tell the system that calendarItemModel.ParentCalendarItem should always be TModel (a class derived from Model.CalendarItem) in order not to use constructions like OfType<TModel>().